# Get deleted documents in local storage

Tags: couchdb, couchbase-lite

I am using CouchBase Lite 1.4 with Android over CouchDB 1.6
I would like to list all the  `_deleted` documents on my local database 
Once I get all I would like to purge it
So

```
Map<String, Object> deleted  = null;

            Database master = CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getMasterDataBase();
            QueryOptions queryOptions =  new QueryOptions();
            queryOptions.setStartKey("_deleted");
            queryOptions.setEndKey("_deleted");

            try {
                deleted =  master.getAllDocs(queryOptions);
            } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("deleted", "we have " + deleted.size());
```

With this code I am not getting anything . 
What I am doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get only the deleted docs via query, but you can query all documents with included delete doc and then filter with `document.isDeleted()`.

[how to query with included deleted doc](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/1.4/java.html#all-documents-queries)